# Margins on my page are too wide, How to reduce the margins in html page

Tags: html, css

I am building a basic React application. The issue is that when I run the application without any CSS I get wide margins on the page.

[image]

Below is my code for the index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAq06l5RUVfib62IYRQacLc-KAy0XIWAVs"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
 <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
 </html>
```

Is there a way to eliminate these margins?

Comment: are you sure there is no CSS .. am pretty sure there is a max-width set to container (bootstrap thinking ...)

Comment: There is no css but there is this ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/48938155eb24b4ccdde09426066869504c6dab3c/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">''' I wasn't able to add in the code above.

Comment: as expected, there is bootstrap .. so change `container` with `container-fluid`

Comment: When I do that the whole page disappears.

Comment: I got rid of the bootstrap and it seems to work now.  I left it as container.

Comment: flex layout is a great way to solve such issues. Have a look here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/